# Substitute variable with bucket name

Tags: aws-cloudformation

I have this template that works as expected and creates a S3 bucket and a few athena queries.

https://datameetgeobk.s3.amazonaws.com/cftemplates/athena_saved_query_blog_partition_parquet.tpl

The question is:
How do I replace S3 bucketname "athenadata162a" with the bucket name created in the first step.

> external_location = 's3://athenadata162a/optimized-data11/'

The code that created a new bucket looks like this...

```
"myS3Bucket" : {
      "Type" : "AWS::S3::Bucket"
      },
```

---

As suggested, changed the code to yaml and still getting this error:

> Template validation error: Template error: One or more Fn::Sub
>   intrinsic functions don't specify expected arguments. Specify a string
>   as first argument, and an optional second argument to specify a
>   mapping of values to replace in the string

The code:

```
Resources:
  myS3Bucket:
    Type: 'AWS::S3::Bucket'
  createTableASParquetPartioned:
    Type: 'AWS::Athena::NamedQuery'
    Properties:
      Database: default
      Description: Create table as parquet partitioned
      Name: Blog2createTableAS
      QueryString: !Sub
        - |-
          CREATE table new_parquet11 WITH (format='PARQUET',
          parquet_compression='SNAPPY',  partitioned_by=array['year'],
          external_location = 's3://myS3Bucket/optimized-data11/') AS SELECT
          id, date, element, datavalue, mflag, qflag, sflag, obstime,
          substr("date",1,4) AS year FROM original_csv WHERE
          cast(substr("date",1,4) AS bigint) >= 2015 AND cast(substr("date",1,4)
          AS bigint) <= 2019
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically you use [`Fn::Sub`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-sub.html) to substitute variables in some input string.

In your case in YAML this would be something like:

```
    QueryString: !Sub
      - |-
        CREATE table new_parquet11
        WITH (format='PARQUET', 
        parquet_compression='SNAPPY', 
        partitioned_by=array['year'], 
        external_location = 's3://${myS3Bucket}/optimized-data11/') 
        ...
```

Sorry I will not provide JSON syntax as it is too horrible for multiline values.

Comment: @shantanuo See YAML example [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-sub.html#intrinsic-function-reference-sub-example.yaml). YAML syntax is a bit tricky, you might need to experiment a little bit.

Answer (score 0):

You can do `external_location = 's3://${myS3Bucket}/optimized-data11/'`.